# some issue regarding page refresh

Tags: asp.net

I have made a sample website in asp.net. On page load and on button click i have called RandomNumber function which is displayed on lbldispnum.

now i have stored the random number in a session and on page refresh the label lblsipnum displays random number and that what i want.

this works after more than one post back.
not when we run the website  and then click on page refresh , the control enter loop not is postback and displays new random number ,how to avoid this or bypass this ifloop on page refresh
Please help me to find out the solution to this problem i have mentioned both aspx code and vb code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

</div>
<p>
<asp:Label ID="lbldispnum" runat="server" BorderColor="Black"
BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"
        style="z-index: 1; left: 295px; top: 101px; position: absolute; width: 339px;     height: 28px"></asp:Label>
</p>
<p>
    &nbsp;</p>
<p>
    <asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server"
        style="z-index: 1; top: 192px; position: absolute; left: 378px; height: 26px; width: 104px"
        Text="Submit" />
</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>


Partial Class RereshTest
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles  Me.Load

If Not IsPostBack Then

Session("CheckRefresh") = Server.UrlDecode(System.DateTime.Now.ToString())
lbldispnum.Text = RandomNumber(8000, 10000)
End If

End Sub


Private Function RandomNumber(ByVal min As Integer, ByVal max As Integer) As Integer


Dim random As New Random()

Return random.[Next](min, max)

End Function



Protected Sub btnsubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsubmit.Click
If Session("CheckRefresh").ToString() = ViewState("CheckRefresh").ToString() Then
lbldispnum.Text = RandomNumber(8000, 10000)
Session("RandNumber") = lbldispnum.Text
Session("CheckRefresh") = Server.UrlDecode(System.DateTime.Now.ToString())
Else
lbldispnum.Text = Session("RandNumber")

End If


End Sub

Protected Sub Page_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
ViewState("CheckRefresh") = Session("CheckRefresh")
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I am following you.
It sounds like you want to load the page, see a random number, then reload the page and see the same random number.  If this is the case I think the following will work.

In the Page_Load() function you will need to set the Session("RandNumber") value to the value you set in the textbox.  Something like this should do:

```
lbldispnum.Text = RandomNumber(8000, 10000)
Session("RandNumber") = lbldispnum.Text
```

I am a C# person so forgive me if there is VB syntax errors.

Do this within the if statement that checks for postback.  Also within this if add a check to see if the Session("RandNumber") variable contains a value.  If it does contain a value, use it, otherwise do what you are doing and populate the field with a new random value.  The submit function gets executed after the Page_Load() so it should handle overwriting the textbox with a new value if I am reading it correctly.

I didn't try to figure out your usage of the CheckRefresh variable, but I am pretty sure it is not needed if you implement the solution correctly.